# Запись в файл символа

Tags: c#, файлы

Здраствуйте, как записать в файл (C#) кавычки ("")?

Comment: Допустим так `streamWriter.Write("\"");`

Comment: Открыть файл для записи. Записать. Закрыть файл.

Comment: @nick_n_a формально это пример записи в поток, а не в файл. По мне так в вопросе недостаточно информации. Что пробовали, что не работает, как пишут в файл - ничего из этого не ясно.

Comment: Я предполагаю что автор не знает что такое экранирование. я показал экранирование `\"` как самый частый вопрос.

Comment: @nick_n_a кстати, возможно автору надо писать не в файл как таковой, в в строковую константу в коде на C#. В общем, без деталей можно только гадать в чем вопрос.

Comment: Ну тогда File.WriteAllText("s.txt","\""); - записывает в файл кавычки :)

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы вывести кавычки, нужно воспользоваться `экранированием символов`.

Внутри строк экранирование символов осуществляется с помощью символа '\'.

Пусть `s` - строка, которая будет записана в файл.

```
string s="На вывеске магазина красовалась надпись \"Посторонним вход воспрещён\"";
```

Значение переменной `s` после выполнения кода:

`На вывеске магазина красовалась надпись "Посторонним вход воспрещён"`

Думаю, ясно, как пользоваться экранированием символов.

Если что-то непонятно - опишу ещё подробнее.